# undo sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER

Tags: docker, sudo

recently I did a sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER command. It made my linux behave funny, getting stuck at finishing screen of restart, not opening chrome a single time. I would like to undo it. didn't find anywhere online how to do it. would love some help!

thx in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can remove `$USER` from `docker` group -

`gpasswd -d $USER docker`

Ref - https://linux.die.net/man/1/gpasswd

Comment: Thx! I already reinstalled linux. it gave me too many bugs which I didn't know to fix.

Comment: So you're removing the user: root from the docker group ?!?